# Logging the last time user signed in Node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, database

I need to log the last time the user signed in using my node.js server. I am looking into three options. The persistence requirement is not super high, meaning that the margin of error of this record being recorded is open.

1. Use SQL DB and whenever the user logs in it modifies their profile account.
2. Record it in a server text file. So whenever the user logs on, this file will be opened and updated. The opening, recording and closing of the file will all be done asynchronously.

I'm thinking that the second option is the better on because I'm using SQL for many other operations so I prefer to not interrupting my DB as much as possible.

One concern I have for the second option is the performance hit on the server that will be caused by the frequently read and write to a local text file.

I'm curious what other people who have gone through this path thought about my thought process. Any opinions or tips are highly welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should use a SQL database, it is a much more better way than the plain text.

The main problem with a text file is that when you log in, you can simply append a line (but what about a couple of user loggin in at the same moment ? You have not any warranty that all the access are logged), but when you want to extact the last login for a user, you should read (and then load) all the file from the start (or the end), which can cause a really worst problem than the access to the DB.

Naturally you can work out all the problems with a text file, but then you have written a lot of code to avoid a simple update query.

I don't think that, with the information you give, you should be worried about the performance of a database access in this case.